# Keeping value of variable assigned to "this"

Tags: java

I'm trying to achieve the following

```
Model model1 = this;
this.remove(index);
Model model2 = this;
```

and then I want to compare `model1` and `model2` and see what's changed. However, as soon as I call remove, `model1` is also changed. Is there a way to keep `model1` fixed? I've tried final, and it yields the same result. I also tried using arrays, which also did not work.

`this` is `DefaultListModel`

Docs for DefaultListModel

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html

Comment: This question is unanswerable without knowing exactly what `getModel()` returns and what `remove(...)` does. It looks like `getModel()` returns mutable internal state, and `remove(index)` mutates that state.  Is that correct?

Comment: It is very unclear what you are trying to do. Some more relevant code would help in determining the problem (i.e. the definitions of `remove()` and `Model`).

Comment: Edited the post with further clarification. the getModel was actually redundant, I forgot to take it out. "this" is a DefaultListModel from JavaFX.

Comment: You will need to make a new object.

Comment: It sounds like you don't understand what the assignment operator (`=`) does.  It does not create a copy of its right hand side.  In your example, `model1` and `model2` refer to the *same object*, so obviously they are always going to be identical.

Comment: That was very clear to me, thank you. Do you have suggestions?

Comment: javafx doesn't have a default list model. The one you linked to, you would do `Model model1 = new DefaultListModel(); for(int i = 0; i<this.getSize();i++) model1.add(this.get(i));`

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
Model model1 = this;
```

you are actually assigning the Object reference `this` points to to the variable `model1`. When you do

```
Model model2 = this;
```

you're doing the same, assigning the same `this` reference to the variable `model2`. In your code, you end up with `this`, `model1` and `model2` all pointing to the same object. It doesn't matter through which reference you'll change the state of that single object, it's still the same object and you'll see the same state through any of those variables. What you actually need is a copy of the object with all relevant state variables being copied, usually called a *copy* or a *deep copy*, depending on your specific requirements. Whether it's enough to create a new instance of `DefaultListModel` and adding all elements from the current instance to the new model is enough, or you actually need to create copies of those objects too, depends entirely on your use case.